# How to set a FILE Name while downloading a file from FileReader?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file

I'm trying to download a file from a server using FileReader, when it downloads the file like `download.zip`, but I want to set some different file names here.

```
        var newBlob = new Blob([blob], { type: blob.type })
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(e){
        window.location.href = reader.result ? reader.result.toString() : "";
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(newBlob);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can update the file name of what you want using the reader.fileName

```
var reader = new FileReader();
 reader.fileName = file.name // file came from a input file element
 reader.onload = function(readerEvt) {
    console.log(readerEvt.target.fileName);
 };
```

Comment: There is no "fileName" property available for reader. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

Comment: reader.fileName won't accept here. Since reader don't have that field "fileName"